# Add a row number using window functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have the following table in input:

```
FootnoteField               FootnoteText
Field1                      blabla
Field2                      blabla 
Field3                      blabla 
Field4                      zzzzzzzzzz 
Field5                      blablabla 
Field6                      ploof
```

How could I add an incremental integer column, that assigns the same integer for rows where FootnoteText is identical? This is what I am looking to achieve here:

```
FootnoteField                   FootnoteText       Number
Field1                          blabla               1
Field2                          blabla               1
Field3                          blabla               1
Field4                          zzzzzzzzzz           2
Field5                          blablabla            3
Field6                          ploof                4
```

Comment: what version of SQL server?

Comment: do you need this number ordered by FootnoteField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need your data ordered by `FootnoteField`, you can go with GoatCo answer.

But if you do then:

```
with cte as (
    select
        FootnoteText, FootnoteField,
        min([FootnoteField]) over(partition by FootnoteText) as min_FootnoteText
    from Table1
)
select 
    FootnoteText, FootnoteField,
    dense_rank() over(order by min_FootnoteText)
from cte
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1cee6/6)</kbd>**

Comment: @GoatCO damn,  thanks, thought about accumulated sums recently and how it's not working in SQL Server 2008 :(

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY FootnoteText)
FROM YourTable
```

You only need `PARTITION BY` if you want the numbering to start over for each value in some group, ie for each day I want numbering to start at 0, so `PARTITION BY Some_Date`

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1cee6/1/0)

Comment: please create sqlfiddle demo with it :)

Comment: coming... sql fiddle is having issues

Comment: Was trying to create a fiddle too to prove you right.. works on sqlexpress right here - good that text to ddl is still working ;)

Comment: Fiddle posted.  If it were ordered by FootnoteField every line would have a different value.

Comment: @GoatCO it's not what I'm saying. In OP output row with blablabla have number 3, in your output it'll have number 2

Comment: So it looks like dense_rank, but you should give it ordered by FootnoteField

Comment: @RomanPekar Ah, I see what you're saying, will have to see what OP was after.

Comment: many thanks guys. Both solutions bring value for my issue, however, having the data "ordered" by FootnoteField is more suitable for my purpose.